# Hibernate create query using join columns in where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a table where the table structure is like this

```
package com.abc.domain;


@Entity
@Table(
    name = "ENTITY_DTL"
)

public class MyEntityDtl implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int NATLTY_CD_LENGTH = 3;


    @Id
    @Column(
        name = "MY_ENTITY_DTL_ID",
        unique = true,
        nullable = false
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "myEntityDtlIdSeq"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "myEntityDtlIdSeq",
        sequenceName = "MY_ENTITY_DTL_ID_SEQ",
        allocationSize = 1
    )
    private Long MyEntityDtlId;



    @ManyToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(
    name = "ENTITY_ID",
    referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_ID",
    nullable = false
), @JoinColumn(
    name = "ENTITY_TYPE_CD",
    referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_TYPE_CD",
    nullable = false
)})
    private MyEntity myEntity;


    /* 
    other columns and their getter setter 
    */


}
```

Here- what i want to achieve is  -  something like this

Join MyEntityDtl  table with Abc table using this columns -  ENTITY_ID and ENTITY_TYPE_CD .

How can i achieve it without using MyEntity table in the query.

As that will cost me additional join in this situation

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the extra join ? As long as it is in the way many -> one, it won't really cost anything in term of performance (check you didn't forget index though). Unless I'm missing something some might call that "premature optimization".

Comment: The only way I know is to add your Abc table as another ManyToOne association to your MyEntityDtl table

Comment: @Walfrat - you are correct , as the fetch type lazy is true - fetch = FetchType.LAZY , i can add a join and it won't affect the performance also

Comment: posted the answer below - for createQuery using entity manager

Answer (score 1):

As the fetch type is lazy , i van directly make use of join column for creating the join, it will not affect the query performance becuase of fetch type lzay -

```
 Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT abc FROM ABC abc, MyEntityDtl medtl join medtl.myEntity  me " +
                        " WHERE vsf.rqstId = me.entityId AND  " +
                        " me.entityTypeCd = '?' AND " +
                        " medtl.SOME_OTHER_COLUMN= '?' " ;
                query.setParameter("entityTypeCd", VALUE);
                query.setParameter("SOME_OTHER_COLUMN", VALUE);
```